# Jquery ui tabs component without separate content divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I need to use a tab component of some sort and was looking at jquery-ui. It's already in the project I'm working on. But I don't want to have separate content divs as the controls for the content of each tab are all the same. Basically the UI includes a dropdown, a couple of text boxes and some radio buttons. The only thing dynamic are the items in the dropdown, captions for text boxes, etc. So I merely need to update these when I get a tab click event. The number of tabs is unknown until the component is initialized and the tabs are added dynamically.

Is there a way to do use the jquery-ui tabs control in this manner? In other words, without content divs? When I tried it this way, the tabs don't behave as expected (active tab color, etc., don't work as they normally do).

Comment: I would just put some buttons down, and use javascript to toggle your dynamic content. There is no need for JQuery Tabs in that aspect. Would be overkill.

Comment: you were quite right and this ended up being quite trivial.